# Codename One images not loading

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, codenameone

The image(s) is in the "src" folder. Everything was working fine, until this morning I keep getting a black screen when I run the simulator with
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: stream == null!"

```java
import com.codename1.system.Lifecycle;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Application extends Lifecycle {
    @Override
    public void runApp() {
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = Image.createImage("/icon.png");
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setIcon(image);
        Form form = new Form(BoxLayout.yCenter());
        form.setLayout(BoxLayout.xCenter());
        form.add(label);
        form.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to include the full error stack, but I kept getting an error stating that I'm posting mostly code and to add more details.

Comment: Note: just printing the exception is the wrong approach. Just let it bubble and crash your app. OR: in case you want to ignore the failure in a robust way, pub the `label.setIcon(image)` ALSO into the try block. When that exception is thrown, image will still be null. No point in setting a null icon ...

Comment: @GhostCat I understand, thanks. But I still get the "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: stream == null!" error. The simulator screen is completely black.

Comment: You can't let the exception bubble since the method is a callback and this is a checked exception. But add `Log.e(e)` into the catch block. NEVER do a blank catch block. 

If you use Maven the image needs to be in the resources directory not in the src directory.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog You can let bubble up things by turning them into a runtime exception for example.

Comment: @GhostCat I am indeed aware of that. In this case it's a bad idea. This is a callback which will trigger a crash instead of proper stack. Furthermore, nested exceptions don't always look great in CN1 because the early versions didn't include the `cause` chain. Just reporting the exception here makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't let the exception bubble since the method is a callback and this is a checked exception. But add `Log.e(e)` into the catch block. NEVER do a blank catch block.

If you use Maven the image needs to be in the resources directory not in the src directory. Like you see [here in the KitchenSink](https://github.com/codenameone/KitchenSink/tree/master/common/src/main/resources). Under `common/src/main/resources`.

Comment: Once again, Thanks much. That definitely worked. I had to create the directory.